# regular expression with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I manage time log below.

```
Section/TeamName/age/NAME/[Jan/Feb/Mar....etc].txt
```

**Example:**

```
EngineeringDepartment/TeamA/25-30/John/Jan.txt
```

But I want to pick up each employee time log.

**Example:**

```
cp EngineeringDepartment/TeamA/25-30/John/Jan.txt ./total/John/Jan.txt
```

I wrote tiny script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.txt" | awk -v FS="/" '{system("mkdir -p ./total/" $5)}'
find . -name total -prune -o -type f -name "*.txt" -print | awk -v FS="/" '{src = $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/" $5 "/" $6; dst = "./total/" $5; system("cp " src " " dst)}'
```

This script is not smart! Any good smart method?

Comment: are you looking to make a total file for each employee, that is a the grand total of hours for all available months? Good luck.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for. Can you use `mkdir total; cp -r */*/*/* -t total`?

Answer (score -1):

Forget find and awk; write a simple shell script.

Since you have a fixed multi-level hierarchy, you can match that with a glob pattern:

For each file, you can do some basic path name manipulation to produce the cp command.

```
mkdir total                                   # Example data:
for file in */*/*/*/*.txt ; do                # EngDept/TeamA/25-30/John/Jan.txt
   sec_team_age=$(dirname $(dirname "$file")) # EngDept/TeamA/25-30
   name_month=${file#"$sec_team_age/"}        # John/Jan.txt
   mkdir -p $(dirname total/$name_month)      # mkdir -p total/John
   cp $file total/$name_month                 # cp $file total/John/Jan.txt
done
```

I didn't have your data to test this, but I manually executed the steps of the loop body using the EngDept/TeamA/25-30/John/Jan.txt example data to make sure the strings looked right.